# HTML element : Attribute ordering

Tags: html

Analyzing several pages and noticing different approaches/writing styles, I am wondering if  the order of HTML element attributes effect:

- browser performance
- rendering (noticeable or not)
- client/server computational resources
- anything?

Is their a standard for the ordering that I should consider?

I can only think of it effecting JQuery selections of nth attribute.

ie:

```
<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>
```

vs

```
<div id="bar" class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I doubt it has any impact on anything. The HTML is parsed into DOM which does not have a concept of attribute order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the querying side:

- Using IDs for selectors O(1) instead of selecting by class O(n)
- Use classes for selections of multiple elements, IDs for selections with only one element (this will cause you to only use either an id or a class, usually never both)

On the rendering side:

- Minimize browser reflow ( https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow )
- CSS: Use a declaration only once ( https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-css )

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter it is usually a style decision or which ever you need format first via js or css.  [HTML Attributes Explained](http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/html/attributes-basic/)